# Security logging for Android

Tags: security, logging

How can an Android phone log all activities related to access?

My requirement is that every phone lock, unlock event, any settings modification, and audit trail needs to generate a log entry to a file.

Examples -
Successfully unlocking a phone by pin. The log should have an entry of the date and time and specifically mention phone was unlocked by the method of the pin.

Same for the phone lock. The log should say the phone was locked at this date and time from screen timeout reason.

The log should say the phone was unlocked by biometrics at this date and time using fingerprint 1. Specifying the type of verification, and what fingerprint/identifier was used.

The log should say a new biometric, new fingerprint 2 was added at this date and time.

Detailed access, and audit trail logs, just like in the security world of PC/computer, server, Linux.

Comment: The only way I see to realize that would be to build a custom ROM. Settings, lock screen, biometrics and so on are areas where apps don't have access to, may be even system apps. So the only way would be to build a custom ROM and modify all those parts of Android in a way that the generate such an audit log.

Comment: @Robert This should just be a functionality of the Android kernel

Comment: You may want to look at Android Mobile Device Management (MDM)/Enterprise Mobility Management (EMM) solutions for security logs, https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.policies#logtype Manufacturer specific solutions like [Samsung Knox](https://www.samsungknox.com/en/knox-features/android) may have additional granularity.